# VPN tunnel IP is 172.16.4.2, how can I see what IP's/Subnets are on the other side?

Tags: vpn, subnet

This is the ifconfig:

```
utun2: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1340
    options=6403<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,CHANNEL_IO,PARTIAL_CSUM,ZEROINVERT_CSUM>
    inet 172.16.4.2 --> 172.16.4.2 netmask 0xffffffff
    inet6 fe80::aede:48ff:fe00:1122%utun2 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x11
    inet6 fc00:af6d:6058:7873:9685:4033:8217:541 prefixlen 64
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
```

I know it will allow connecting to 10.14.0.0/16 space.

How do you find out all of the subnets that are on the other side of the VPN tunnel?

Answer (score 1):

You can never tell what is on the other side of a tunnel. You may get routing from the VPN server or set it otherwise, but you never know if it is complete or even if it is correct. You cannot even be sure what the other end is in fact. The only way to know that is by inspecting the server (and the connection).

Related:

- [What is “push route” used for in OpenVPN?](https://superuser.com/questions/1093664/what-is-push-route-used-for-in-openvpn) on superuser.

Comment: Thanks. That's interesting.  So if the VPN server doesn't provide routing and you don't know what to manually set, will any traffic be routed to that tunnel?  Or it will all go to the default gateway since there's no routing set for that tunnel?

Comment: @mutant_city Traffic goes where it's routed. If it's not routed, it doesn't go anywhere.

Comment: Thanks.  That's really interesting and makes sense.  Does one have to specifically program the routes to publish when setting up the VPN? And when someone connects to the VPN those routes will be propogated down to them?

Comment: @mutant_city Yes - unless you want something else. See eg https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91071/openvpn-push-a-route-to-client-with-a-different-gateway

Comment: @mutant_city To be clear - maybe some VPNs send some default roots by default or set them in client certs. Depends on VPN.

Comment: Dope thanks! That helps immensely and clears up a huge source of confusion I had about how VPN traffic works.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently viewing the routing tables will show all of the subnets for the interface.

```
$> netstat -r
10.14.1/24         link#17            UCS          utun2
10.14.2/24         link#17            UCS          utun2
10.14.10.10/32     link#17            UCS          utun2
```

Edit: For better specificity, according to @tomasz below, a VPN has to specifically provide the route to the connecting machine otherwise there will be no knowledge of the subnets on the other side of the tunnel.